# Running asyncio functions in parallel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm pretty new to programming in Python and programming in general. I'm trying to run an `asyncio object (A Discord bot in specific, using the discordpy library)` on top of a GUI, but I'm running into some problems when it comes to getting both of these things to run in parallel. As far as I know, there are three solutions to approaching this problem.

- The first solution which I haven't tried yet is, is using aysncio, but I don't think this will work, since my GUI and the Discord bot are two separate main loops.
- I then tried to use multithreading, but after some experimentation I learned that asyncio is not thread safe and that caused problems when I tried to get more than one bot online.
- I finally tried multiprocessing, which is thread safe, and seemed to be my best bet at getting everything to work, but the method for serializing that the multiprocessing library uses can't pickle asyncio objects, and returns an error whenever I try to launch a bot.

So I'm really stuck here, it seems like every solution there is has some complications or limitations that won't let me accomplish what I'm trying to do. How should I go about this? Would asyncio work?

Comment: Can you describe exactly how this would work, or maybe even write a toy version that tries to do what you want?  Do you want an interface that controls a discord bot, or a bot that sends data to an interface?  You probably can run both in the same event loop, but you'll run into problems if either needs to do something computationally intensive

Comment: I want to run several separate bots that all send info to an interface, and can all also access eachothers data. I feel confident I know how to go about all of this, but can't get multiple bots to run at once.

Comment: Maybe a shared database between the bots, with a multiprocessing message queue(s) between the bots and interface.  Don't both passing asyncio objects around, you should be able to pass all the information you need as strings and numbers, maybe some basic `dataclasses`

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to keep it all together but if there's no way to do it, I think what you suggested should work.